# ValidateMenuItem is not getting called for NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

Here is my sample class and usage:

```
@interface CCocoaMenuItem : NSMenuItem 
{
   someClass *someobj;
}

 - (void)menuEventHandler:(id)target;
- (void)setEnableItem:(BOOL)nEnabled;

@end

@implementation CCocoaMenuItem

- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)item {
    // return YES or NO based on some conditions;
// But this method is not getting called


}

@end
 CCocoaMenuItem *dummyItem = [[CCocoaMenuItem allocWithZone:[NSMenu menuZone]] initWithTitle:(NSString*)aStr action:nil keyEquivalent:@""] autorelease];
[dummyItem setAction:@selector(menuEventHandler:)];
[dummyItem setTarget:dummyItem];
```

here validateMenuItem is not getting called. I have set the action and target. Target is this class object itself and I have defined validatemenuItem in this class only.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: You assigned selector of `menuEventHandler:` as an action, how `validateMenuItem:` is supposed to be called ?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've posted, `CCocoaMenuItem` only declares the `menuEventHandler:` method in the `@interface`, but doesn't actually implement it. Menu items aren't validated if their target doesn't respond to the selector you've set as the `action` (such menu items are disabled automatically).

Btw, `menuZone` is meant for `NSMenu`, not `NSMenuItem`.

Comment: Well, menuEventHAndler: is implemented in the CCocoaMenuItem. I forgot to add it in the questions. Sorry for the typo.. So this should not be the reason. Anything else? I have also checked that setAutoEnableMenuItems is checked. Could not see what else might be going wrong here. Thanks for any help

Comment: I've pasted your code in an empty project, added an `menuEventHandler:` implementation to the `CCocoaMenuItem` class, added an item of that class to a menu, and `validateMenuItem:` was called just fine. There must be something else in your actual code that isn't in your question. How are you actually putting the dummy item in a menu, so that it's shown on screen?

Comment: Yes, it is getting shown in the menu but always disabled. I am trying to show that menu in the System menu (Apple menu). Can that make a difference?

Comment: Do you mean the menu with the Apple logo () on it or the one with your app's name?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call `validateMenuItem:`, because it is a delegate method of `NSMenuDelegate`,
you have to do something like this:

```
@interface CCocoaMenuItem : NSMenuItem <NSMenuDelegate>{
   someClass *someobj;
}
```